# What is a proper usage IntentFilter class/object?

Tags: android, intentfilter, clearance

I did quite a reading about Android recently and I came across something that confuses me.
The problem is in what occasions it is appropriate to instantiate the IntentFilter class?

I'm aware of the the model that Android uses AndroidManifest.xml and how Android matches intents against the declared filters, but I still cannot figure out what would be a proper usage of IntentFilter class?

I doubt that it is for dynamic declaration of filter in run-time..

Can you, palls, help me figure out what would be a proper usage of an IntentFilter instance in an application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `IntentFilter` is for a `BroadcastReceiver` to know which intents to receive.